# ~ Paths resolved differently after upgrading to ASP.NET 4

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, webforms, asp.net-4.0

We're upgrading a large system to ASP.NET 4, and we've discovered a strange issue with the way paths starting with `~` are resolved for some of our Ajax requests. Our Ajax requests use Server.Execute, and the pages they execute have paths that start with ~. However, in ASP.NET 4, it seems like this path is being resolved incorrectly, treating "MyService.aspx/MyMethod" as if MyService.aspx was a folder. This is different to ASP.NET 3.5.

I've created a small sample to show the issue.

I've managed to reproduce the issue in a small sample:

#### ~/Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("jquery", "1.6.4");
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.text);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

#### WebService1.asmx.cs

```
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        var tw = new StringWriter();
        tw.WriteLine("VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(\"~/Images/Blah.png\"): " + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Images/Blah.png"));
        tw.WriteLine("VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(\"~/Images/Blah.png\"): " + VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative("~/Images/Blah.png"));
            // Hack to use ResolveClientUrl without including a Server.Execute in the sample
        tw.WriteLine("new Image().ResolveClientUrl(\"~/Images/Blah.png\"): " + new Image().ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/Blah.png"));
        return tw.ToString();
    }
}
```

If you run this same code on ASP.NET 3.5 and ASP.NET 4, you'll get different outputs:

```
3.5
---------------------------
VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Images/Blah.png"): /MyTest1/Images/Blah.png
VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative("~/Images/Blah.png"): ~/Images/Blah.png
new Image().ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/Blah.png"): Images/Blah.png

4.0
---------------------------
VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Images/Blah.png"): /MyTest1/Images/Blah.png
VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative("~/Images/Blah.png"): ~/Images/Blah.png
new Image().ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/Blah.png"): ../Images/Blah.png
```

The first two calls are the same, but the `ResolveClientUrl` call behaves differently. Note: We're not actually calling `ResolveClientUrl` like this, it's inside an ASPX page that is `Server.Execute`'d, I just did this to keep the sample small - the issue appears to be the same.

So... Is this a bug? Is there any way I can make this work the same as in ASP.NET 4 to avoid having to move things around so that the paths work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [this may be a deliberate change (bug fix?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099336/resolveclienturl-works-differently-in-asp-net-4-and-3-5/6282823#6282823) in ASP.NET 4.0, so that paths are returned correctly so that browsers would interpret them, eg.

```
/MyFolder/MyPage.aspx/Something/Something
```

In ASP.NET, the URLs would be incorrect, because they'd be based off `/MyFolder/MyPage.aspx`.

I don't think the ASP.NET 3.5 behaviour was really ever correct, it's just what we used because that's how it was, so it's now become broken.

My solution for now, is to move the asmx files up one level, so they're a level above the pages their content is being written in to. This is a bis nasty, and only works if your pages are in a folder, but it's easier than rewriting how this works!

Comment: Some more information can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099336/resolveclienturl-works-differently-in-asp-net-4-and-3-5

Comment: That's the article my first line links to ;-) We ended up moving our services (luckily, all files that call them are in a subfolder, else this wouldn't work). Probably shouldn't been a compatibility switch for this :-(